Airflow dags are running automatically
I am running airflow at remote ec2 machine(through VPN) and for to access the WebUI i configured nginx server. The configurations which I followed is:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name; #EC2 instance's IP address

    location /home/airflow/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080; # Airflow webserver address
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

My issue is when I place DAG file at DAGS folder it was automatically running it and the run's are not showing up at airflow WebUI side.
I checked my DAG file the:
default_args = {
    'owner': 'SYSUSER',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,  # Number of retry attempts
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)  # Time interval between retries
}


schedule_interval=None,
catchup=False

